# How to conditionally set an object property when the asignee is undefined

Tags: javascript, error-handling, null

I am trying to conditionally set an object property in JS, but am getting the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

This is being thrown by `secondary.address`.

```
let address = {
  prop: primary.address || secondary.address || null
};
```

Is there a clean way to set `address.prop` in a cascading fashion by casting `secondary.address` to `null` instead of throwing an error?

Comment: Check primary and secondary for null.  Set address accordingly.

Comment: So it must be broken out into several lines? I was hoping to use a ternary operator or something more concise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`shorCircuiting &&`](https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-conditionals-bbc13ac3e9eb)

```
let address = {
  prop: primary && primary.address || secondary && secondary.address || null
};
```

Or you can use [`Optional Chaining`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) this is stage 2 proposal, if your project already using `babel` you can use [`babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining)

```
let address = {
  prop: primary?.address || secondary?.address || null
};
```

Comment: I like the second one.

Comment: What would short-circuiting look with a more complex object like... `req.body.address.id` and `defaults.address.id`?

Comment: @Matthew you have to do it like `req && req.body && req.body.address && req.body.address.id` one level access at a time, in similar way you can do for `defaults.address.id`

Comment: And method 2 is only available with Babel?

Comment: @Matthew yes, it is at present `stage 2` proposal not the part of ES spec, but in queue

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help!!